# Ceridian Dayforce is not returning data from "backgroundJobQueueItemId" in the ODATA APIs response

Tags: rest

We are trying to connect Ceridian dayforce APIs but we are getting the expected output in the result details below :

API 1 :

```
https://ustest232-services.dayforcehcm.com/Api/ddn/V1/EmployeeExportJobs/?clientNamespace=ddn&isValidateOnly=false
```

Response :

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Message": "Employee Export Background Job queued successfully",
        "JobStatus": "https://ustest232-services.dayforcehcm.com/Api/ddn/V1/EmployeeExportJobs//Status/11835"
    }
}
```

API 2

```
https://ustest232-services.dayforcehcm.com/Api/ddn/V1/EmployeeExportJobs/Status/11835
```

Response :

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Status": "Succeeded",
        "Results": "https://ustest232-services.dayforcehcm.com/Api/ddn/V1/EmployeeExportJobs/Data/1ef7c4c4-d84a-457c-8e40-46e08ecb9b9c"
    }
}
```

API 3 :

```
https://ustest232-services.dayforcehcm.com/Api/ddn/V1/EmployeeExportJobs/Data/1ef7c4c4-d84a-457c-8e40-46e08ecb9b9c
```

Response :

```
{
    "Data": "",
    "Paging": {
        "Next": ""
    }
}
```

This is a demo tenant, what could be the issue for not getting any data?